# Google Analytics - do display features get sent with event hit?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Will the event sent in this code contain the display features data?

```
ga('create', 'UA-99999999-1', 'auto');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'event', 'Telemarketing visits', 'visit-for-something');
```

My goal is to see users' age under Google Analytics events, but I'm not sure whether that needs a pageview as well?

From [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/display-features) I can see "Note: It's important that you require the plugin after creating the tracker and before sending the **pageview**.".

Comment: "before sending the pageview" means before calling `ga('send', ...)` first time.

Answer (score 1):

'Age' is a built-in dimension in Google-Analytics. To enable it, you may want to visit your GA dashboard page. Select the Audience tab on the left vertical menu. Select Demographics >> Age. Follow the instructions mentioned.

Comment: It answers the question. Build in means it do not pass through your tracker, but is derived from another signals in doubleclick network and it is displayed in your google analytics reports.